# Apache Ignite - Java Thin Client terminated

Tags: java, caching, server, ignite

> i am using apache ignite 2.8.0.
>    this is my code for connecting the Java thin client to server,

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");
try (IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg)) {

    System.out.println("Thin client started.");
    final String CACHE_NAME = "sample";
    ClientCache<Integer, Object > cache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);
    cache.put(1,"JP");
    System.out.println(cache.get(1));  

  } //main method



 } //class
```

> it prints JP successfully, but after that my thin client is terminated.
>   is there any way to keep alive my thin client?
>   this is my exception..

```
    [21:48:34,942][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to process selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesSent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1583770713875, hashCode=1387062740, interrupted=false, runner=grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null, closeSocket=true, outboundMessagesQueueSizeMetric=null, super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/127.0.0.1:10800, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:51279, createTime=1583770713811, closeTime=0, bytesSent=83, bytesRcvd=92, bytesSent0=83, bytesRcvd0=92, sndSchedTime=1583770713875, lastSndTime=1583770713875, lastRcvTime=1583770713875, readsPaused=false, filterChain=FilterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerBufferedParser, directMode=false]], accepted=true, markedForClose=false]]]
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:276)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:245)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:223)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:358)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1162)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2449)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2216)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1857)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: I guess it's because you used try-with-resources here when you create the client. Your client was autoclosed. Please create the client instance outside the try-with-resources block.

Comment: I tried, but the sample result. it throws the following exception on server side - " Failed to process selector key"

Comment: Try to check the code from my answer below.

Comment: Can you also provide the full exception?  Failed to process selector key - the current message should be related to something else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried the following code:

```
ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");

IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg);

System.out.println("Thin client started.");
final String CACHE_NAME = "sample";
ClientCache<Integer, Object > cache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);
cache.put(1,"JP");
System.out.println(cache.get(1));

//here your client will be alive
```

Comment: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/java-thin-client-initialization-and-configuration

Comment: in this documentation i found, IgniteClient is an auto-closable resource. what is the meaning of this?

Comment: Please, check the docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html, so if you use try-with-resource pattern, a client will call close() method when it leaves the try block

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a known and fixed issue [IGNITE-12032](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-12032). Please check with 2.8.0 release (available for [download on Apache Ignite website](https://ignite.apache.org/download.cgi) and elsewhere) to see if it actually goes away.

Comment: i am using 2.8.0 only

Comment: I have tried running this code multiple times with 2.8.0, and never got this error message. Please re-check using minimal reproducer.